# How to implement SAML for SSO using ADFS as identity Provider

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, saml-2.0, adfs

After 2 days of research ,now i am at assumption that ADFS can be used as Identity Provider which uses Active Directory as its Repository (this means we can store Username,password... required to identify user) .My confusions are

- When a user opens a login Page in SP ,and if there is trust
  relationship between SP and ADFS(IP) ,does the IP takes the windows
  logged in UserId to check user from active directory ?
- If the authentication is successful then does IP sends
  UserInformation(as a SAML responce) to SP ,so that i can create
  session for logged in user ?
- what should i do ,if user logs out from SP ,should i also have to
  clear session in IP(now ADFS)

if my assumption are right ,how to implement ADFS as Identity Provider (IP) and consume its service in Asp.net Application (Service Provider) ?

Answer (score 2):

1. When the SP notices that the user is not signed in it sends the user to the IDP. This is where the login page is presented. ADFS can be configured to authenticate the user based on the signed in windows user.
2. Yes ADFS can be configured to return user information in the SAML response. This is defined as claims in ADFS
3. When the user is logged out in the SP, the SP should send a SAML LogoutRequest to the IDP to remove the session on the IDP.

[Here is a library I have seen others use for .net](http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLSuite.aspx)
Another option is to use a product such as [Shibboleth](http://www.internet2.edu/products-services/trust-identity-middleware/shibboleth/) in front of you application

Comment: ,so when a user login to his PC by active directory username and password ,then when opening the service provider URL ,he do not have to  reenter his username and password (this means there will be no windows security popup window),can ADFS can be configured in that way ? if yes can you explain me how ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is: "How to implement ADFS as Identity Provider (IP) and consume its service in Asp.net Application (Service Provider)"

Then you have tagged it with SAML?

Why do you want to use SAML? (And here I am talking about SAML the protocol NOT SAML the token).

Just use WS-Federation and WIF which is OOTB support. WS-Fed also uses SAML tokens.

If you want to use SAML, refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) and [SAML : ASP.NET MVC application talking to SAML IDP](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/04/saml-aspnet-mvc-application-talking-to.html) .